# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file \bin\Debug\aspnetdb.mdf failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, connection-string

I am developing a Class Library in C# and in this Class Library I am trying to access database through ADO.NET code, But I'm getting this error. I don't know what is the reason behind it. So please tell me how can I solve it.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\vivek.nuna\Documents\VisualStudio2005\Projects\SubsystemSyncService\TestClient\bin\Debug\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

This is the connection string I am using.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RegistrationConnString" 
         connectionString="Server=192.168.101.145\SQLEXPRESS;Database=***_HubDB;User Id=sa;Password={C8273EFD-LB2F-4E65-8702-14B61PI08A9}" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Note: I can't see a file `aspnetdb.mdf` in the `Debug` folder.

This is the code, how I am using ado.net code.

```
private DataSet GetAddressFieldsAccordingtoAddressId(string strAddressId)
{
        try
        {                
            strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "[dbo].[PL_spPLUIGetAddressFieldsAccordingtoAddressId]";
            command.Parameters.Add("@lAddressID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(strAddressId);
            command.Connection = connection;

            DataSet dsPwd = new DataSet();               
            SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            dAdapter.Fill(dsPwd);

            command.Dispose();
            dAdapter.Dispose();

            return dsPwd;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have added reference of this class Library in a C# form.

C# form is calling this method of class library.

Comment: try this [one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fafe818f-8aa3-46cd-bb69-55e540e7a62e/an-attempt-to-attach-an-autonamed-database-aspnetdbmdf-failed?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a standalone database for your application, you should have a look at

SQL Server Compact : http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

SQLite : http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

For connectionstrings see http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2003/.

```
SqlCeConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlCeConnection();
sqlConnection1.ConnectionString = "Data Source = C:\\Users\\Administrator\\My Documents\\BMS_Data.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
```

Comment: He's already using a `.mdf` = SQL Server database file - not sure why you start talking about Access.... (that would be a `.mdb` file - **not** `.mdf` !)

Comment: friends I m very new into this world, please explain more.
I am not getting what you people are discussing